# Logging according to Common Base Event (CBE) format using SLF4J

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

I need to emit log files compatible with the IBM CBE (Common Base Event) specification and I was wondering if there was a way to have SLF4J do that without code changes, maybe using a specific log4j layout class or something. Does IBM or other 3rd party vendor provide such class?
Thanks

Comment: Was any solution found?

Comment: Nope and I changed jobs so I didn't have to solve this anymore.